# Token Example Module

Tags: tokens

I am working on an extension that is going to use a custom token from Drupal content. I found the great example [blog post from CiviCRM 4.1](https://civicrm.org/blog/colemanw/create-your-own-tokens-for-fun-and-profit) but it appears that in CiviCRM 4.7 tokens switched to using `Civi\Token\TokenProcessor`. I have looked at a few extensions that do not appear to be using this model. Is there a good example (other than the documentation) of the new model.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fair to say the new `Civi\Token\TokenProcessor` model is still evolving, but the older method still works and is the easier option for now unless it is not sufficient for your needs.

You can find a range of extensions doing things with tokens [here](https://civicrm.org/extensions?title=&body_value=token&field_extension_cms_tid=All&field_extension_ready_value=All&sort_by=field_extension_current_usage_value&sort_order=DESC)